# What does ''食べろっていう'' mean

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form, anime, imperatives

> ちょっとこれ１本でどうやって食べろっていうのよイヤがらせ？

I was watching Gabriel Dropout, Episode 2, and then I came across with that sentence, but I don't get the logic behind it.

Why is taberu even in imperative form? What does verb in imperative form + っていう mean?

For more context, this is their conversation:

> Vignette:ガヴ割り箸取ってくれない？
> Vignette:ありがと
> Gabriel:ほれ
> Satania: ちょっとこれ１本でどうやって食べろっていうのよ
> Satania: イヤがらせ？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68958/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42544/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19688/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ちょっとこれ１本でどうやって食べろっていうのよ」
:Why do you say "eat" to me by just one of this chopstick? (How can I eat it?)

It is used as an antonym.

Omitted「」on 食べろ may be making you confused.